# someone hacked us, I deleted that user acc. & created a new one but now missing most menus in Admin

Tags: admin, admin-login, admin-user, adminmenu

Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme

Someone hacked our Magento, deleted all user accounts and created one for themselves with a user ID = shopmanager1. I connected via cPanel's phpmyAdmin, deleted their user account, created a new user account, assigned it Admin priviliges. It now let's me login into Admin but most menus are missing (we only have Catalog, CMS and a little bit of SYSTEM - mostly extensions I installed). How can I get all the other menus back? How did this happen in the first place?

Comment: I think your first step should putting your store on maintenance mode and applying all the security patches.

Comment: Please see answer to a related question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237537/data-security-has-been-compromised/

Answer (score 0):

-If you have git on the site , add git status to see for any change on the files.
-Download your magento version from https://magento.com/tech--resources/download as it was new and run a diff compare with your site to see for any file missing/update.
-When you run backups (sql) dont let them on root folder , because they are accessible from hackers. 
-As Vivek said install the require patches.